# load DIV content from other domain using JQuery load/ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, cross-domain

I have a requirement where I have to load a content in a DIV from a domain other than source domain.

**Eg:**

```
$("#myDiv").load("https://www.google.com")
```

Now in above example, I want to load **google** page content into a DIV on my JSP.

Now, the problem is request is blocked due to browser's same origin policy.

I have gone through some solutions to set headers at server. But I am not suppose to alter headers in this case as this may affect other aspects of my application.

Also, solutions like YQL may not work as I am not suppose to make java script/ ajax call to other locations due to som security concerns.

I am currently looking for a `library / api / workaround` or any open source solution that can address my problem.

P.S: I am working with `servlets and JSP`

Any suggestions/solution please.

Thanks in advane.

Comment: Fetch them from the 3rd party on your web-server instead of the client browser and return content from your own server. The restrictions will not apply then. e.g. You could write a simple service that returns the HTML of a specified URL. (note: this does not give you the right to use the 3rd party content)

Answer (score 0):

If source domain is yours or you can change the return value then you can do jquery ajax call with the data type jsonp. If you can't access the source domain then this is not possible because of security reasons. 
As an another solution we can use small proxy which manage requests and responses, but again you should have rights to access the source domain.

look at this,
[image]

proxy can comunicate with the server 2 without any restrictions since which are in the same domain. And you can implement proper interface in proxy which allow to communicate with external servers or clients like server1. Using this model you don't need to change server 2.

Comment: I am pretty sure he does not own `www.google.com` :)

Comment: @nishan can you please further explian "small proxy which manage requests and responses".